# Create a DependencyProperty that takes any Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, dependency-properties

I want to include a 'units' `DependecyProperty` in a `UserControl`. Units are defined in separate enums e.g.

```
public enum TemperatureUnits {
    Celcius,
    Fahrenheit,
}

public enum PressureUnits {
    Psi,
    Bar,
}
```

and so the `DependencyProperty` needs to be able to accept enums of any type. I tried using a 'generic' `DependencyProperty` using `Enum` as a type as follows but it crashes saying the default value is not valid ...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Units",
        typeof(Enum), typeof(DialInputWidget), new PropertyMetadata(0, UnitsPropertyChanged));
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Any particular reason for this approach? Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: The user control is an input dial that can show pressure or temperature (or potentially others), there is another `DependencyProperty` enum that configures which. However it behaves slightly differently based on the units, e.g. Fahreneit increments in whole steps, Celsius in half steps. When I write the XAML I'd like to declaritively state e.g. 'I want a dial to show temperature in Celcius'

Comment: Does it work if you use "int" instead of "Enum"?

Comment: @Brendan Given that in a physical world we have a limited amount of different types of units, I think I'd personally suggest doing a generic abstract class, with a generic DependencyProperty with something like `where TEnum : struct, IConvertible` and have separate derived controls for different unit types. IMHO having a generic control for any unit type, that has a very specific handling for one specific instance of one specific unit type breaks SOLID. This approach also ensures type safety - no `Units.Celcius` for pressure control this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "int" instead of "Enum".

Also, isn't the default optional?  Omit it and it will be initialized to the equivalent of "0" in the Enum.